# UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr Obsolete

Tags: c#, dll, interop

I have this 3-party dll and the import declarations they provide uses UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr for marshaling strings. Works without problems.
However, VS now says that UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr is obsolete.
I have tried LPWStr and other species without success (access violation....).
Is there a way to get around this? I can not change the dll, no source for that.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31006

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.